# How to get a list with only unique numbers? (Python)

Tags: python, list, duplicates, unique

I want to write a program that checks for duplicate values and removes them.
So for example I want from this:

`list = [2,6,8,2,9,8,8,5,2,2]`

To get only this:

`uniques = [6,9,5]`

I can't seem to find a good way to compare every item with each other to see if they are equal and them remove them. Any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
list = [2,6,8,2,9,8,8,5,2,2]
uniques = []
for i in range(len(list)):
    if list.count(list[i])==1:
        uniques.append(list[i])
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter                                         
>>> lst = [2,6,8,2,9,8,8,5,2,2]                                             
>>> c = Counter(lst)                                                        
>>> [x for x in c if c[x] == 1]                                             
[6, 9, 5]
```

Other than using `count` or `in` for each element, this should be O(n) instead of O(n²).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to preserve the order of the elements too, follow this best method :

```
uniques = list(dict.fromkeys(list))

print(uniques)
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you want a list of values that appear only once in your list, this should work. I used a hashmap to store the count of values in the the list and then added the keys which have a count of 1 into `unqiue`.

```
l = [2,6,8,2,9,8,8,5,2,2]
unique = []
count = {}

for i in l:
    if count.get(i) is None:
        count[i] = 1
    else:
        count[i]+=1

for i in count.keys():
    if count[i] == 1:
        unique.append(i)

print(unique)
```

**Output**

```
[6, 9, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def unique(x: list):                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    a = set()                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    for i in range(len(x)):                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        if x.index(x[i]) == (len(x) - 1) - x[::-1].index(x[i]):                                                                                                                                                                  
            a.add(x[i])                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    return list(a)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
print(unique([1, 2, 1, 11, 4, 4, 6, 3, 2]))                                                                                                                                                                          
# [3, 11, 6]
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful, of better quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

```html
list = [2,6,8,2,9,8,8,5,2,2]
uniques = []
for i in list:
    if i not in uniques:
        uniques.append(i)
```

Comment: The code works, but your question would be a little better if you added an explanation as well.

Comment: The code does not work. It results in `[2, 6, 8, 9, 5]` while the OP asks for `[6,9,5]`. Besides, do not use JavaScript snippets for Python code.